# JS, JSON: How to get the n first items respecting 2 conditions?

Tags: javascript, json

**Given data such** :

```
var people = [ 
{ 'myKey': 'A', 'status': 0, score: 1.5 },
{ 'myKey': 'C', 'status': 1, score: 2.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'D', 'status': 0, score: 0.2 },
{ 'myKey': 'E', 'status': 1, score: 1.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'F', 'status': 0, score: 0.4 },
{ 'myKey': 'G', 'status': 1, score: 3.0 },
];
```

**How to get all items with `'status':1` such**

```
var people2= [ 
{ 'myKey': 'C', 'status': 1, score: 2.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'E', 'status': 1, score: 1.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'G', 'status': 1, score: 3.0 },
];
```

---

**Edit:** 
My final aim is to get the n=2 items with `'status':1` in ascending order, such:

```
var people3= [ 
{ 'myKey': 'E', 'status': 1, score: 1.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'C', 'status': 1, score: 2.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'G', 'status': 1, score: 3.0 },
];
```

My approach is one function to get from `var people` all items of `'status':1` into `people2` (it's the code I'am asking right here), one fn to sort `people2` by ascending score (`people3`), then one fn to pick `'myKey':` value of the `n=2` first items. So I get

```
var people4 = [ 'E', 'C' ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getMyKeys(top) {    
   var result = people.filter(function (item) {
          return item["status"] === 1; //only status=1
       })
       .sort(function (a, b) {
          return a["score"] - b["score"]; //sort 
       })
       .slice(0, top) //top n
       .map(function (item) {
          return item["myKey"]; //return "myKey" property only, if needed.
       });
   }
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fr8Lv/6/)

Comment: I liked the `a.score - b.score` bit in the `sort` function.

Comment: Artyom, how can we turn this into a named function that I may reuse several time ? (I am begginer)

Comment: @Hugolpz I edited my solution to vary the `n` parameter (top n records). Does that suit for your reusing?

Comment: @Art: works ! I spent the afternoon on that trying hundreds ways. This suit my use beautifully !

Answer (score 1):

Use the new `filter` method to conditionally reduce the set of items in the array.  Once reduced sort the items by passing a comparison function to `Array.sort()`

```
var people = [ 
{ 'myKey': 'A', 'status': 0, score: 1.5 },
{ 'myKey': 'C', 'status': 1, score: 2.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'D', 'status': 0, score: 0.2 },
{ 'myKey': 'E', 'status': 1, score: 1.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'F', 'status': 0, score: 0.4 },
{ 'myKey': 'G', 'status': 1, score: 3.0 },
];

    var selected = people.filter(function(e){
        return e.status == 1;
    });

    selected.sort(function(a,b){
       if(a.score < b.score){return -1;}
       if(a.score > b.score){ return 1;}
       return 0;
    });
```

If you must support older browsers you may need to build the `.filter` method into the browser.  This [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on MDN contains a native implementation of `.filter` that can be added to the browser.

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/5zt3A/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to fiter filter by status, then sort by score and then to map only myKey

```
var people = [ 
{ 'myKey': 'A', 'status': 0, score: 1.5 },
{ 'myKey': 'C', 'status': 1, score: 2.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'D', 'status': 0, score: 0.2 },
{ 'myKey': 'E', 'status': 1, score: 1.0 },
{ 'myKey': 'F', 'status': 0, score: 0.4 },
{ 'myKey': 'G', 'status': 1, score: 3.0 },
];

var result = people.filter(function(i) {
    return i.status == 1;
    })
    .sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.score == b.score) return 0;
        if (a.score > b.score) return 1;
        return -1;
    }).map(function(i) {
        return i.myKey;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GrYuK/1/

Answer (score 1):

Putting up with another set of answer, I prepared a [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/cLSLZ/) that you can view for more details.

```
  (function getPeopleStatus (person){
    for(var ctr = 0; ctr< person.length; ctr++){

    if(person[ctr].status === 1){
        selection.push(person[ctr]);
    }

}
    selection.sort()
  })(people);
```

Comment: I don't understand, link not working + "person" should be "people" right ? I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hugolpz/cLSLZ/1/)

Comment: if you are pertaining to the last line of the code, which is `(people)`, it just passes the people object to the function which is in turn will be used as 'person' within it. Moreover, I viewed your code, no need to fire a function if its already and immediately invoked function. I hope this clears up the confusion.

Comment: Yes it clarify things. I'am was not familiar with this way to create the generic function and put the parameter at the end. Thanks you!